# preparing output data in the main MEX gateway function

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing, matrix, mex

I am writing a wrapper function using mex which is used to call the C function. Generally, I used to create the output matrix in the main gateway function using

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(r,c,mxREAL);
```

or

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(3, dim_array, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
```

to store the output image.  Now I have a function which returns only long integer value instead of an image. How do I handle this output? Do I need to create a matrix for a single value output or are there any other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "long integer".  Follow the table below to select the type of your newly created array (`mxClassID`) to match the desired MATLAB and C type.  To cheat a little, you can use `mxClassIDFromClassName` to get the class id from the MATLAB type (e.g. `mxClassIDFromClassName('single')` to select `mxSINGLE_CLASS`)

[image]

If you mean you want to **create a scalar**, just create an array of size 1-by-1 with [mxCreateNumericMatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatenumericmatrix.html):

```
mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxClassIDFromClassName('int32'), mxREAL)
```

Also note that there is a convenience function for creating a `double` scalar, [`mxCreateDoubleScalar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublescalar.html):

```
mxArray *ps = mxCreateDoubleScalar(initialValue);
```

All of the `mxCreate*` functions are listed on the MathWorks reference page [Create or Delete Array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/create-or-delete-array_buu4p6_-3.html).